# mobile connect/disconnect event

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, mobile

When my websocket server loses a connection due to a mobile phone disconnecting from the internet, I can periodically check for one every fraction of a second, but that is inefficient.

Is there an event I can listen for to trigger this instead that only occurs when a user connects to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PhoneGap [online](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online)/[offline](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline) events.